# Windows 10 WIFI static Internet Connectivity Status

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I was looking around to force Windows 10 to think my WIFI always has internet connectivity

but all the things I have tried which I found few of them in superuser.com they didn't work I even tried hosting `/ncsi.txt` and `/connecttest.txt` on localhost using WAMP and the host file to redirect `www.msftncsi.com` and `www.msftconnecttest.com` to 127.0.0.1

So I was wondering how I can do that like no matter if my WIFI has internet connectivity Windows 10 would show I have internet connectivity

Comment: If your internet is out so Wi-Fi has no internet, there is no way to force Windows 10 to believe it does have internet.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Moab Well Windows keeps killing the Wireless Display when my wifi doesn't have internet connectivity even tho I am using a plan cable and Wireless Display is using lan

Comment: https://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/ not sure if this will be the same in Win8/win10. But you will at least know **how** it works

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows keeps killing the Wireless Display"? WLAN should work normally even without internet connections since it can be used to access LAN that doesn't have access to the internet for whatever reason.

Comment: @Albin XD exactly I am as confused as you about that so I that's the reason I looking into fixing it like this

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Well I didn't disable EnableActiveProbing but I routed those address to 192.168.1.2 which is my LAN instead of localhost and it's kind of working although does it have any downsides if I disable EnableActiveProbing

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "Windows keeps killing the Wireless Display"?!

Comment: @Albin Well simply when the WIFI loses internet connectivity it disconnects my display there isn't anything else it just does it

Comment: still don't get it, a screen shot would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well after testing a bunch of things I got it working this way

1. Added a virtual host in WAMP and pointed it to 192.168.1.2 hosting `/ncsi.txt` and `/connecttest.txt`
2. Running DNSCrypt listening to 127.0.0.100 for DNS
3. Modifying host file to

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
# 102.54.94.97 rhino.acme.com # source server
# 38.25.63.10 x.acme.com # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.100 131.107.255.255
127.0.0.100 dns.msftncsi.com
192.168.1.2 www.msftncsi.com
192.168.1.2 www.msftonnecttest.com
192.168.1.2 msftncsi.com
192.168.1.2 msftonnecttest.com
192.168.1.2 ipv6.msftconnecttest.com
```

4. Also added cloaking rules in addition to the host file for DNSCrypt

```
################################
#        Cloaking rules        #
################################

localhost                127.0.0.1
localhost                ::1

131.107.255.255                127.0.0.100
dns.msftncsi.com                127.0.0.100
www.msftncsi.com                192.168.1.2
www.msftonnecttest.com                192.168.1.2
msftncsi.com                192.168.1.2
msftonnecttest.com                192.168.1.2
ipv6.msftconnecttest.com                192.168.1.2
```

5. Registry changes

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet]
"ActiveDnsProbeContent"="127.0.0.100"
"EnableActiveProbing"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I know it might be pointless to change `ActiveDnsProbeContent` while `EnableActiveProbing` is disabled but just to be sure